# SWIG C++ structure to java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

I'm trying to get a simple SWIG example to work that uses a struct as a return type, but my generated file is incorrect. My files look like this.

```
SwigTest.h
#pragma once
#include "MyHeader.h"
class SwigTest
{
public:
    MyHeader testMe();
};

MyHeader.h
struct MyHeader {
    int x;
}
```

and my swig interface file is:

```
%module MyModule
%{
#include "SwigTest.h"
#include "MyHeader.h"
%}
extern MyHeader testMe();
```

The resulting JNI file has the following method declaration

```
public class MyModuleJNI {
  public final static native long testMe();
}
```

If my method returns a primitive, it works fine, but not with the struct. I'm running on windows with `swig.exe -java -c++ MyModule.i`

EDIT: I think I need to declare a struct in the .i file as well. Could someone confirm (or dispute) that? Thanks.

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Hey @Jeff ! Have you come up with any solution ? kindly help if you have resolved your issue

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to declare the struct in the interface file as well.

Try this:

```
%module MyModule
%{
#include "MyHeader.h"
#include "SwigTest.h"
%}

%include "MyHeader.h"
%include "SwigTest.h"
```

Also its safer to declare the struct before the code that makes use of it.